# Redirect after submit form

Tags: 8, forms

I use this code in my form ( buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) ) :

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\test\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Drupal\user\PrivateTempStoreFactory;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Session\SessionManager;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class TestForm extends FormBase {

    public function getFormId() {
        return 'TESTOLDTONEW';
    }

    public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        \Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();

    $a['ad_mail'] = [
        '#type' => 'email',
        '#title' => t('Email ID:'),
        '#required' => TRUE,
    ];
    $b['total'] = [
        '#type' => 'hidden',
        '#attributes' => [
            'id' => 'actionsubmitid',
        ],
        '#value' => '0',
    ];
    $c['actions']['submit'] = [
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => $this->t('Finalize the purchase'),
        '#button_type' => 'primary',
    ];
    $test= [
        '#theme' => 'test',
        '#a' => $a,
        '#b' => $b,
        '#c' => $c,
    ];

    return $test;
    }

    public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    }

    public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        $form_state->setRedirect('test.new');
    }

}
```

Now I want redirect to a machin name ( for example "test.new" ) that create in routing.yml file . I use `$form_state->setRedirect('test.new');` in "submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)" but not work .

EDITED :

.routing.yml

```
test.old:
  path: '/test/old'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\bpay\Form\TestoldForm'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'

test.new:
  path: '/test/new'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\bpay\Controller\TestnewController::new'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

Comment: There is nothing in what you've described that would stop that redirect from happening. So your problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: No all of codes are this .

Comment: Ok. Your problem lies in the code you didn't show.

Comment: Code is work just redirect not work . How can I fix this ?

Comment: I don't know - I can't see your code

Comment: can you please post all of the code ?

Comment: All of code is here.Other code is : https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/form-api/introduction-to-form-api

Comment: Show the routing definition.

Comment: I edit question .

Comment: When I change $c to $test , redirect worked but whit this dont work.

Comment: Look at my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `buildForm` method needs to return `$form`. Not `$test`. You're missing key items by ignoring the `$form` variable. Properly set the form items (not as their own variable) and remove the custom theme hook you're trying to do. Cut this down to its simplest pieces first just to get it working and go from there.

Get rid of `$a $b $c` variables as that doesn't make any sense, just use `$form`. Your submit info is not making it into the form itself, which is why it isn't working.

Comment: Good observation. I didn't even realize that.

Comment: I cant do this because I want use $c as theme and if I use all of them with $form ,  I cant use my theme and show all $form var in page without theme

Comment: That's wrong. You cannot just send elements from a form piecemeal like that. You have to handle it differently. You must allow the system to properly build and render these elements for it to work. Theming it is a different issue altogether.

Comment: Kevin is correct.

Comment: Very thanks but how can I use theme in this example?

Comment: I don't understand what `test` is supposed to be as a theme hook or what it's definition is. But just make the suggested changes and your form will act the way you expect. Then, open a separate issue about how to theme a form the way you want to.

Comment: This question is an example and I create a shopping basket with table (by sessions) and forms.I want select tabels in my html.twig theme that create in my module,then show forms in place that is select in theme.I ask this question ti recive answer how can I do that in my real code.

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with the original question, which is "why does my form not redirect?" - which has been answered above. Please open additional questions for different issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the redirection in form action,

```
// Get the routename
$routename = 'test.new';
  $url = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute($routename);
  // make the redirection
  $form['#action'] = $url->toString();
```

Comment: I don't think manually setting the `#action` is a best practice of Drupal. It should be handled in the redirect of the form.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be because you are killing the cache with this:

```
\Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();
```

Remove that and see if your redirect works.

Comment: When I change $a and $b and $c to $form and return $form, redirect worked but whit this dont work.

Comment: I remove that but still not worked.