# How can I change form action link?

Tags: 8, forms

How can I change form action in drupal 8?

In default, page not change and when my form path is `/site/drupal/page`, my form action is `<form data-drupal-selector="test" action="/site/drupal/page" method="post" id="test" accept-charset="UTF-8">`.

But I want change it to other page. How can I do this ?

** Redirect not worked, see this link: [Redirect after submit form](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/232387/redirect-after-submit-form)

Answer (score 4):

In the form submit handler, you can modify the $form['action'] value.

```
// Get the routename
$routename = 'My-Route';
  $url = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute($routename);
  // make the redirection
  $form['#action'] = $url->toString();
```

Comment: Can you paste the form build code? This should work

Comment: Form build code is here : http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/232387/redirect-after-submit-form

Comment: You haven't set the #action in that code.

Answer (score 1):

in the submit form write a redirect

```
use Drupal\Core\Url;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

//add the below in submit form handler. Use the route name you want to redirect
$response = new RedirectResponse(Url::fromRoute('<front>')->toString());

$response->send();
```